# Render a HTML source into an image (png, gif) - Cocoa, Applescript, Automator evrything is welcome

Tags: html, perl, cocoa, applescript, automator

I am trying to convert some HTML-source into an image. Finally I want to do this on the commandline but my search brings me to this idea, to use a little Cocoa app to do the work.

Applescript or Automator may offer contribution to my problem as well?

One solution I may consider may be webkit2png, a python script. http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/

So how else could I render my HTML into an image (png, gif, jpg)? Is there a straightforward method built in?

Comment: PhantomJS is popular for this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any built-in way to do it with AppleScript or Automator, but I also use [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/).

This saves a clipped image (-C) at 100% scale (-s 1):

```
webkit2png -C -s 1 -W 1000 -H 1000 --clipwidth 1000 --clipheight 1000 http://t.co
```

-F only saves a full size image:

```
webkit2png -F http://stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called “Fake” (available in Mac App Store) which is an AppleScript-able Web browser. One of the things it can do is save the viewport rendering as an image file. You can build a workflow within the app or write some AppleScript:

```
tell application "Fake"
    capture web page as screenshot saving in file ((the path to the desktop folder as text) & "Screenshot.png")
end tell
```

You an also resize the window to various sizes as you take screenshots, and capture as PNG, PDF, HTML, or Web Archive.

The PNG or PDF renderings that are created are the full-length rendering, similar to what you get as output from WebKit-to-PNG.

The thing that makes Fake stand out over other similar solutions is that you can script interactions before a screen shot. A key application of Fake is to have a script impersonate a user for website testing, so you are able to take screenshots that are more than just how the page looked when it loaded. For example, you can have Fake fill out and submit a form and take screen shots as you go or after the form is submitted. You can also capture animations by taking a screenshot every 3 seconds or whatever, because you’re capturing a live browser view in an interactive Mac app.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I didn't describe the background: I am looking for something small and headless running in the background. You know Geektool? This can only display plain text or images. What I was trying to achieve is generating some nicely formatted output, rendering it and then capturing the result into an image to be displayed by Geektool. Recently I found a Geektool replacement running on Node.JS offering to display formatted text natively. Geektool seems to be a dead end so I will invest into that road: http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/